# Same column ( different row ) operations in R

Tags: r

I have a big database and I'm trying to create a new column starting from an existing one doing the difference between elements in consecutive cells ( same column, different row):

| existing_column | new_column |
| --- | --- |
| A | A-B |
| B | B-C |
| C | C-D |
| D | D-E |
| ... | ... |
| Z | Z-NULL |

The way I'm doing it is to duplicate existing column into a dummy one, remove first element, adding NULL as last element and subtracting the existing column and the dummy one ... is there a better way? Thank you

```
exist <-c("A","B","C","D","E")    
db<-data.frame(exist)    
dummy<-exist[-1]    
dummy[length(dummy)+1]<-"NULL"    
new_col<-paste(exist,"-",dummy)    
new_col    
db<-data.frame(exist,new_col)    
db
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(existing_column = LETTERS)
df %>% mutate(new_column = paste(existing_column, lead(existing_column, default = 'NULL'), sep = '-'))
   existing_column new_column
1                A        A-B
2                B        B-C
3                C        C-D
4                D        D-E
5                E        E-F
6                F        F-G
7                G        G-H
8                H        H-I
9                I        I-J
10               J        J-K
11               K        K-L
12               L        L-M
13               M        M-N
14               N        N-O
15               O        O-P
16               P        P-Q
17               Q        Q-R
18               R        R-S
19               S        S-T
20               T        T-U
21               U        U-V
22               V        V-W
23               W        W-X
24               X        X-Y
25               Y        Y-Z
26               Z     Z-NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
transform(
  df,
  new_column = paste(existing_column, c(existing_column[-1], NA), sep = "-")
)
```

which gives

```
   existing_column new_column
1                A        A-B
2                B        B-C
3                C        C-D
4                D        D-E
5                E        E-F
6                F        F-G
7                G        G-H
8                H        H-I
9                I        I-J
10               J        J-K
11               K        K-L
12               L        L-M
13               M        M-N
14               N        N-O
15               O        O-P
16               P        P-Q
17               Q        Q-R
18               R        R-S
19               S        S-T
20               T        T-U
21               U        U-V
22               V        V-W
23               W        W-X
24               X        X-Y
25               Y        Y-Z
26               Z       Z-NA
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with numeric data just represented as characters in your example, you can use mutate() and lead()

```
df<-data.frame(old_col=sample(1:10))
df%>%mutate(new_col=old_col-lead(old_col, default = 0))

   old_col new_col
1       10       4
2        6      -3
3        9       8
4        1      -1
5        2      -5
6        7       3
7        4       1
8        3      -5
9        8       3
10       5       5
```

Answer (score 0):

In case there is a need of a fast data.table version

```
dt[, new_column:=paste(exist, shift(exist, type="lead"), sep="-")]
```

Edit. Turns it isn't much faster:

```
df = data.table(exist = rep(letters, 80000))
> m = microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
... a = df %>% mutate(new_column = paste(exist, lead(exist, default = 'NULL'), sep = '-')),
... 
... b = transform(
...   df,
...   new_column = paste(exist, c(exist[-1], NA), sep = "-")
... ),
... 
... d = df[, new_column := paste(exist, shift(exist, type="lead"), sep="-")]
... )
> m
Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
    a 292.2430 309.6150 342.0191 323.9778 361.0937  603.8449   100
    b 349.4509 383.3391 475.0177 423.8864 472.0276 2136.2970   100
    d 294.6786 302.8530 332.3989 315.6228 340.9642  641.8345   100
```